# Spotify long term token with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, spotify

Is anyone knows how to implement long term token process with Spotify iOS SDK. I guess we have to use tokenRefreshURL but that's all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and implemented this solution :
https://github.com/simontaen/SpotifyTokenSwap

Its a ruby script host on server.

It works fine, the fact is that it occurs a dependency on web server.

Like the author of the script I've hosted this script at : heroku.com

If anyone knows another method without the need of web server.